# Type errors when I use RouteComponentProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have a component which renders the routes itself. I want to use RouteComponentProps to access the location attribute but I get some type errors when I changed my component to the following way:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import RouteParams from './Routes';
import { map } from 'lodash';


const App = () => {
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      {map(RouteParams().routes, route => {
        return (
          <Route exact path={route.pathName} component={route.component} />
        );
      })}
      <Redirect to="/a" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  }

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Routes.tsx

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
const A = () => <p>A</p>
const B = () => <p>B</p>
const C = () => <p>C</p>


interface IRouteParams {
  pathName: string;
  search: string[];
  label: string;
  component:
    | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>
    | React.ComponentType<any>;
}

const RouteParams: FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps> = (
  {location}
) => {

  const showForAdmin = true;

  const {search} = location;

  console.log(search);

  const scenarioManagerRoute: IRouteParams = {
    pathName: '/a',
    search: ['a'],
    label: 'a',
    component: A,
  };

  const routes: IRouteParams[] = [
    scenarioManagerRoute,
    {
      pathName: '/b',
      search: ['b'],
      label: 'B',
      component: B,
    },
  ];

  if (showForAdmin) {
    routes.push({
      pathName: '/c',
      search: ['c'],
      label: 'C',
      component: C,
    });
  }

  return { routes, scenarioManagerRoute };
};

export default withRouter(RouteParams);
```

I get errors in the component as well as when I import it. Please advice. Any help is appreciated.

The errors are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: @NicholasTower Updated OP

Answer (score 0):

### There are some issues that I can see in your code. Let me point it out:

1. You defined a functional component: `RouteParams` which is imported and used as an object in `App.tsx` as shown below:

```js
{map(RouteParams().routes, route => {
    return (
      <Route exact path={route.pathName} component={route.component} />
    );
})}
```

2. The functional component `RouteParams` is defined as a functional component BUT, it does not return any JSX (A component should return a JSX). So, technically, it will not function as a Component.

### I've made a few changes to your code.

1. I converted the `RouteParams` to a hook. To do that, I removed the Higher order component `withRouter` (as it is a hook now). Also named it in a conventional hook name `useRouteParams` (this is not mandatory).

```js
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";

const A = () => <p>A</p>;
const B = () => <p>B</p>;
const C = () => <p>C</p>;

interface IRouteParams {
  pathName: string;
  search: string[];
  label: string;
  component:
    | React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>
    | React.ComponentType<any>;
}

const useRouteParams = () => {
  const showForAdmin = true;
  const location = useLocation();
  const { search } = location;

  console.log(search);

  const scenarioManagerRoute: IRouteParams = {
    pathName: "/a",
    search: ["a"],
    label: "a",
    component: A
  };

  const routes: IRouteParams[] = [
    scenarioManagerRoute,
    {
      pathName: "/b",
      search: ["b"],
      label: "B",
      component: B
    }
  ];

  if (showForAdmin) {
    routes.push({
      pathName: "/c",
      search: ["c"],
      label: "C",
      component: C
    });
  }

  return { routes, scenarioManagerRoute };
};

export default useRouteParams;
```

As you might be able to see, I used the `useLocation()` hook from `react-router-dom` to make use of `location`. Rest is same.

2. In our `App.tsx` we will have to make some minor adjustments.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import useRouteParams from "./Routes";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppNavigation />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const AppNavigation = () => {
  const { routes } = useRouteParams();
  return (
    <Switch>
      {routes.map(route => (
        <Route
          key={route.pathName}
          exact
          path={route.pathName}
          component={route.component}
        />
      ))}

      <Redirect to="/a" />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

---

### There you go. Hopefully it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks buddy. One quick question: the showForAdmin value comes from a context. Can I connect this hook to the context and retrieve the data? Will it work? Thanks.